# Moving a bottomless metal shed

Tags: removal, shed, backyard

I have this shed I want to move about 10 meters from its current location in my backyard. This shed is metal, without a floor, sitting on paving stones which appear to have been cemented together.

What is the easiest way I can move this shed to my new location?

[image]   [image]

[image]   [image]

Comment: Once you get this thing moved, please feel free to provide an update with your success or any lessons learned for the next person looking to do this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Prepare the base for the shed and tiles in the new location.
- Unscrew the shed.
- Set it aside.
- Move the tiles to the new location.
- Move the shed onto the tiles.
- Screw the shed down.

If moving the whole shed is too awkward (helpers will help with that, and be faster) you could more fully disassemble the shed to move it in pieces - it came in pieces and was assembled originally. But it's faster to not do that, and they are pretty lightweight.

Don't do this on a windy day. The shed may blow off and damage itself while waiting to be screwed down in the new location.

Comment: looks similar to the 10x10 arrow shed I put together.  If it isn't bolted down two people can lift it up and move it.  assembly / disassembly can be painful.  I think mine had 4000 fasteners.

Comment: Speaking from experience, two 6' (180cm) people can move a 10x10 corrugated shed easily. Somewhere there's a picture of my neighbor and myself moving a similar shed from my backyard to his. Because of a fence between the properties we had to take it out into the street. We were able to lift it up around a foot, which could clear any obstacles, and had another person to tell us which way to go. No damage to shed or people was incurred.

Comment: Between "Unscrew the shed" and "Set it aside", I would build a perimeter frame out of 2x4 lumber under the shed while it is on top of the pavers: Lift one side and slide a board under that wall, then under the opposite wall. If those boards are long enough, they will be useful as handles. Temporarily attach the shed to those boards, and then attach two additional boards between the first two to stiffen the frame. Then four people should be able to lift the entire shed in place without it crumpling like a soda can.

Comment: @spuck Two separate folks have already commented that it should be easily moved by two people and don't mention needing such a contraption, nor crumpling like a soda can.. So based on their actual experiences, probably needless fussing, but if you have one to move, feel free to do it that way.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Well, the shed I used to have like this had a hard time just opening and closing the doors without causing damage. ;) Best of luck to the OP.

Comment: Note that step 1 is much more important than it might at first appear. If you don't ensure the new site is level and properly compacted, then the building may not attach to the tiles all the way around. A leaning shed is both unsightly and unstable.

Comment: So, basically, take it back to its original flatpack form. That's if the bolts have not all rusted !

Comment: Not the first or only suggestion here, @Tim - an option, if help is not available.

Answer (score 4):

I would brace the walls, diagonals and corners so that what ever method of lifting/rolling will not cause it to flex too much.

Perhaps putting one brace between the two long walls and then from that to the corners may be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this helps, of the wall/ceiling assembly is too heavy:

We moved a 10x10 shed whole (ours included the floor), by rolling it over some round fence posts.

Also 4in ABS or PVC plumbing tubing will do.

Use 2x4 lumber to lever it on/off the rollers and fine adjust.

In your case I believe you'll have to separate it from the floor tiles first, and move the wall/roof assembly.